# How can I add a CSS class to a page <head> with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, styles

I want to use jquery to append a new CSS class to the head script of a document to change an element on that page.

It should be simple by using something like this:

```
var myhex = #e6399b;
$("<style type='text/css'> #someid { color:myhex; } </style>").appendTo("head");
```

I've created a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NbbhT/) to test with, but I can't get it to work. I think it's something really simple with the syntax of having a JS variable in the middle of HTML code - I tried `'+myhex+'` and `+myhex+` but to be honest I was guessing at this point.

**Notes:**

1. I need to do it via a variable because the contents of the variable changes often.
2. I realise the immediate answer is "use .css()" but in this scenario I can't use it because I'm adding a style to an element inside a jquery dialog. The only way of doing so is via jquery's `dialogClass` command (i.e. you have to set up the style via a 'class', rather than via `.css()`.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote strings, and add variables to strings with concentanation (+ sign) :

```
var myhex = '#e6399b';
$("<style type='text/css'> #someid { color:"+myhex+"; } </style>").appendTo("head");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NbbhT/1/)