# How to append style into head of any page using jquery instead of string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to append style into webpage through console tab of Chrome browser with the code like this.

```
$('head').append("<style>.hova {border-color: red !important;border-style: solid !important;border: 1px;}</style>");
```

- The problem is it append like a String (return undefinded) in the header with some page like Google or StackOverFlow.
- It works with another page like "http://jonraasch.com/blog/javascript-style-node" (return header of page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append a jQuery script to head tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004667/how-to-append-a-jquery-script-to-head-tag)

Comment: Not every page has jQuery loaded, in which case either the brower-specific function, or a different defined function with `$` as name is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a CSS class to a page <head> with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219188/how-can-i-add-a-css-class-to-a-page-head-with-jquery)

Comment: Also some page, like Stack Overflow or JSFiddle use `iframe` to show your code snippet, so be aware you should check `iframe` head not page.

Comment: If you append it to every page, why not just put it in your style sheet?  By using js, this style will not be applied until the js has loaded and run

Comment: check if jQuery is loaded. type this in console - `typeof jQuery` should return "function".

Comment: Thanks guy but it is not duplicate because the problem is the "<style> ... " can append to the head but it is treated as a String instead of Element.

Comment: 2022 - just tried this in Chrome with jQuery 3.6 and it "does the right thing" - works like a charm. Just FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the native functions instead of jQuery, if you want to do it to every page you visit:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerText = '.hova {border-color: red !important;border-style: solid !important;border: 1px;}';
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: @Hitmands possibly the part where jQuery might not be available to the page

Comment: I would likely think textNode or innerText was safer than innerHTML in this case

Comment: @Hitmands, the OP is trying to use the code on a random page he visits, which is not possible if jQuery is not loaded.

Comment: then propose a change to the question, but always stick to the op.

Comment: Thank you all, this is the correct answer. The problem because i using append with a "String of style". So, some page with know it is a String instead of Element

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "<style>body { background: black; }</style>" ).appendTo( "head" )
```

use appendTo like this.

Comment: It does not work like my script because some page missing jquery. The script of Kevin Drost is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your styles to be treated as an element, you need to put in an HTML element object. Since you're just putting in a string, it thinks you're doing something like adding text to a `<p>` element. Instead, try the following:

```
$("<style>.hova {border-color: red !important;border-style: solid !important;border: 1px;}</style>").appendTo("head");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this and also you add multiple css classes

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
var s = document.createElement("style");
s.type = "text/css"; 
s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(".hova {border-color: red !important;border-style: solid !important;border: 1px;}");
h.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: @Hitmands possibly the part where jQuery might not be available to the page

Comment: In header part, jQuery will not be available.

Answer (score -2):

you can use this:

```
$('head').css({
   'color' : 'red !important',
   'width' : '30px',
   'height' : '10px'
});
```

Comment: Assuming jQuery is available and the page you look at is the document you change